# shading between lines and axes, using PSTricks

Tags: pstricks, shading

I'm trying to figure out how to shade the area bound by 2 lines on a graph, and one of the axes on an x-y plot (technically, the area bound by 2 nullclines on a phase-plane plot). I've mucked about with pspicture, and made several attempts using psclip (based on a guess, and some online examples of shading between functions with >1 intersection point), but without much success. In the following (rather poor) MWE, I've left the axis ticks and labels, to help ordinate. Basiclly, I want to shade (in some color) in the upper=left area bound by the two lines. [If it matters, the two lines intersect at (1.94,2.44).]

Ultimately, I'm looking to generate something looking more or less like this:

[image]

Many thanks in advance to points on how to accomplish with pspicture (although I'm open to alternatives -- say, using tikz).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-0.5)(4,7)
\begin{psclip}{
\pscustom[linestyle=none,algebraic,plotpoints=2000]{
\psplot[algebraic,plotpoints=20,yMaxValue=5.6%,linecolor=cyan
]{0}{2}{x*(-5.5/3.5)+5.5}%
 \psplot[algebraic,plotpoints=20,yMaxValue=5.6%,linecolor=cyan
   ]{0}{2}{x*(-4/5)+4}
   }
  }%
     \psframe*[linecolor=cyan,fillstyle=solid](2,2.2)(4,5.5)
   \end{psclip}
 \psplot[algebraic,plotpoints=20,yMaxValue=5.6%,linecolor=cyan
  ]{0}{3.5}{x*(-1.57143)+5.5}
   \psplot[algebraic,plotpoints=20,yMaxValue=5.6%,linecolor=cyan
  ]{0}{5}{x*(-4/5)+4}
  \psaxes{->}(0,0)(0,0)(6,6.5)
 \uput[-90](5.9,-.1){$H$}
 \uput[-135](-.1,6.7){$P$}
 \end{pspicture} 

  \end{document}
```

Comment: Do you really want to plot the lines as curves, or can you consider plotting them as lines (given by two points)?

Comment: For flexibility (i.e., if/when the nullclines are nonlinear), as curves/functions. I understand that for straight lines, I only need 2 points (which clearly would be easier for this example).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simplified code. The  `\psframe` command and the `psclip` environment are not necessary here if you reorganise the definition of `\pscustom` in the correct order. I also used the optional arguments of `\psaxes` to place the H and P labels.

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-0.5)(4,7)
\pscustom[linestyle =none, algebraic,plotpoints=2000, fillstyle=solid, fillcolor =WhiteSmoke!70!Lavender!]{
\psplot[algebraic,plotpoints=20,yMaxValue=5.6%,linecolor=cyan
]{0}{1.944}{x*(-5.5/3.5)+5.5}%
 \psplot[algebraic,plotpoints=20,yMaxValue=5.6%,linecolor=cyan
   ]{1.944}{0}{x*(-4/5)+4}
  }%
 \psaxes{->}(0,0)(0,0)(6,6.5)[$H$,-110][$P$,-160]
\psset{algebraic,plotpoints=20,yMaxValue=5.6,linecolor=cyan }
 \psplot{0}{3.5}{x*(-5.5/3.5)+5.5}
 \psplot{0}{5}{x*(-4/5)+4}
 \end{pspicture}

  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful -- thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. It's a pleasure to help!

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,pstricks-add}
\begin{document}

\def\F{x*(-5.5/3.5)+5.5} \def\G{x*(-4/5)+4}
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](-3.5,-0.5)(4,7)
  \pstInterFF[PointName=none,PointSymbol=none]{\F}{\G}{0}{I}
  \pscustom[linestyle=none,algebraic,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!30]{%
    \psplot{0}{\psGetNodeCenter{I}I.x}{\F}%
    \psplot{\psGetNodeCenter{I}I.x}{0}{\G}
  }
  \psplot{0}{3.5}{\F}%
  \psplot{0}{5}{\G}
  \psaxes{->}(0,0)(0,0)(6,6.5)[$H$,-90][$P$,0]
 \end{pspicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. I haven't looked at pst-eucl before, but even a quick glance at the summary description of the package suggests it might be a very elegant solution to these sorts of plots generally.